# how to control browser reload event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a Training Management System. I want to notify my students before page reloading on exam. Like if a student wants to reload the page after starting an exam, he will get an alert(sweet alert I think). If a student wants to reload the page forcefully, the exam form will be submitted automatically. I succeed to prevent [ disable right button, keyboard reload ]. But I can't prevent page reloading by clicking browser reload button or url hit... So is there any way to show alert message and get confirmed before page reload using javascript or jquery or laravel or php?

I tried beforeunload event. Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="name" placeholder="Username">
```

Here is my js code:

```
const beforeUnloadHandler = (event) => {
        
        // Recommended
        event.preventDefault();


        // Included for legacy support, e.g. Chrome/Edge < 119
        event.returnValue = true;

Swal.fire({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
            cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                $.ajax({
            url: "controller.php",
            method: "GET",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);    
            }
        })
            }
        });

    };
// works first
        // $.ajax({
        //     url: "controller.php",
        //     method: "GET",
        //     success: function (response) {
        //         console.log(response);
        //     }
        // })


    const nameInput = document.querySelector("#name");

    nameInput.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
        if (event.target.value !== "") {

            window.addEventListener("beforeunload", beforeUnloadHandler);
        } else {
            window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", beforeUnloadHandler);
        }
    });
```

but the problem is ajax request executes before showing the alert in browser and sweet alert shows after clicking leave page or cancel button. I wanted to call an ajax request after the alert shows and confirmed. How can I do it?

It would be a big help for me. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advance.

I tried beforeunload event. Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="name" placeholder="Username">
```

Here is my js code:

```
const beforeUnloadHandler = (event) => {
        
        // Recommended
        event.preventDefault();


        // Included for legacy support, e.g. Chrome/Edge < 119
        event.returnValue = true;

Swal.fire({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
            cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!"
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                $.ajax({
            url: "controller.php",
            method: "GET",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);    
            }
        })
            }
        });

    };
// works first
        // $.ajax({
        //     url: "controller.php",
        //     method: "GET",
        //     success: function (response) {
        //         console.log(response);
        //     }
        // })


    const nameInput = document.querySelector("#name");

    nameInput.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
        if (event.target.value !== "") {

            window.addEventListener("beforeunload", beforeUnloadHandler);
        } else {
            window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", beforeUnloadHandler);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP or Laravel? You haven't shared any such code

Answer (score 0):

You can't custom Modal when user refresh or click back button,but only a default confirm box you can show like this

```js
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         e.returnValue = ""
      });
      window.addEventListener("unload", function (e) {
         $.ajax({
        url: "controller.php",
        method: "GET",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);    
        }
      });
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of what you changed, what the problem was etc. so others can learn. Thanks